# Proper way to ship facebook token from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, token

I'm not sure how to ship a user's fb token from his client to my server. My current approach is the following:

1. User opens webpage and logs in to FB;
2. Token is obtained from FB;
3. Redirect user client to /api/:token
4. Use express + node + `app.get("/api/:token")` to obtain the token on the server

However, this doesn't look safe, since when I redirect the user his token is clearly visible on the browser, and anyone could try to guess a token to impersonate some other user.

Question: how do I safely ship a user's fb token from the client to my server? should I use an ajax post?

Thank you for helping! :D

Comment: Why not use HTTPS??

Comment: @ArunGhosh like in an https.post?

Comment: Enable HTTPS for you site, so everything you sent will be encrypted.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé You mean that someone else can peek token in the browser history?

Comment: @stdob-- yes, after I get the token I simply redirect the browser to https://myapp.com/api/token_i_just_got_from_fb

Comment: _"and anyone could try to guess a token to impersonate some other user"_ – those token values can not be “guessed.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not worry about it, you can secure Graph API requests with [`appsecret_proof`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests):

```
curl \
  -F 'access_token=<access_token>' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=<app secret proof>' \
  -F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]' \
  https://graph.facebook.com
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that link and see what I can figure out! :D

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is there when you post your password and username to the server from the client. Options you have is to

1. Use HTTPS
2. Enctrypt data at client side and decrypt at server